# c# Hackerrank code terminated due to time out but there is no way to optimize this code further?

Tags: c#, optimization, timeout

I was doing a hacker rank challenge in c# to try and bring some of my c skills over to c#. Now I know hacker rank is notoriously stupid with killing programs due to time out (in this case if it lasts more than 3 seconds). But I honestly cannot think of a way to optimize this code further.

Here are the instructions:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation

Basically the challenge is to shift an array of numbers some x amount of times over in the left direction inside the array.

To my knowledge this code is as minimal as it can get and still do the thing they requested. The only way I can think to optimize this code further is to merge the constraint "if(a[i] > 1000000 || a[i] < 1 )" with the writeline forloop at the end of the code, but I tried that and it didn't work.

To me this is literally the minimum number of operations to move the array over by an amount x. But the code fails in test case 7 and 8 (out of 8) due to time out. Am I missing something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
```

{

```
static void Main(String[] args) 

{
    int i, j;
    int temp = 0;
    string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
    string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp,Int32.Parse);

    //constraints
    if(n >= 100000 || n < 1 )
        {
        System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }

    if(k > n || n < 1 )
        {
        System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }  

    for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
           if(a[i] > 1000000 || a[i] < 1 )
           {
           System.Environment.Exit(1);
           }     
     } 

    //double for loop. one adjust position by one. then repeat k number of times.

    for(j = 0; j<k; j++)
        {

            for(i = 0; i< n-1; i++)
                {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                }
        }

    //view array
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
        {
    Console.Write(a[i] + " " );      
        }

}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to answer this, because it's unfair to do challenge for you, especialy one which is so easy. I'll give you a hint. Your two for cycles are executing in 100000*100000 operation, which are roughly about 17 minutes. But why do you perform shifting anyway. Can't you tell which element will move to first position, which to second, after k shifts without shifting k times? Maybe you can just output answer?

Comment: Its the first time I've ever tried to optimize something. I'll see about outputting something directly.

Comment: Thanks man, All green checkmarks now. I wrote the original array to a new array with the updated positions. Its not how I wanted to do it, because I don't think that was the objective of the challenge. But all green check marks none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffling the values one at a time is very slow. There is no need to do this. One can think of the rotation as moving 2 blocks - the values to the left of the rotation point and the values including and to the right of the rotation point

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Rotate this 3 times is

1. move 1-3 to a temp variable
2. move 4-9 to the start of the array
3. move 1-3 to the end of 4-9

**Edit: Add a bit more detail**

We want to rotate the array 3 places.

- move 1 2 3 to a temporary array

  1 2 3
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- move 4-9 to the start of the array

  1 2 3
  4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9
- move 1-3 to the end of the array

  1 2 3
  4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3

We can get away without the temp array for the left hand block if we create a new target array and copy everything to it. The following passes all the tests for the problem

```
 var result = new int[a.Length];
 var block2Length = a.Length - k;
 Array.Copy(a, k, result, 0, block2Length);
 Array.Copy(a, 0, result, block2Length, k);

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result.Select(v => v.ToString())));
```

**Other Points**

The constraints in HackerRank are part of the problem definition - they are telling us what the values can/will do so that we don't have to worry about solving a more general problem

e.g. 
    1 <= a[i] < 10^6

tells us the numbers will all be within the range for standard integers, no need to use `long`  or `BigInteger`. As part of the solution we don't need to confirm these. In a real world situation different rules apply but here we have as much code checking values that cannot be wrong as we have solving the problem.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean here.

Answer (score 2):

I used a queue mechanism to get this working. That way you don't have to do any array copy and just rotating the string to the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution {

    static int[] leftRotation(int[] arr, int rotation) {
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < rotation; i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue());
        }

        return queue.ToArray();
    }

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
        string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp,Int32.Parse);
        int[] result = leftRotation(a, d);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered but there is a different solution that is very fast:

The idea is that you use the periodicity of the shifting. Shifting an element `n+1` times is the same as shifting it `1` time which boils down to `k % n`.
Thus, you can simply create a new array and move the "old" elements directly to the correct spot. See the sample code below:

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
    string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp,Int32.Parse);

    // use the periodicity of the shifting creating a shift between 0 and n - 1.
    int shifts = k % n;

    // Create a new array to hold the elements at their new positions.    
    int[] newPositions = new int[a.Length];

    // You only need to iterate of the array once assigning each element its new position.
    for(int i= 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
    {
        // Here is the magic: (for clarification see table below)
        int position = (i - shifts + n)%n;
        newPositions[position] = a[i];
    }

    foreach(var element in newPositions)
        Console.Write($"{element} ");
}
```

This is more intuitive once you write it down on paper. The table might prints more values than the array contains to show the *actual* positions in the array.

```
-4 -3 -2 -1 | 0  1  2  3  4  (array indices)
=============================
 2  3  4  5 | 1  2  3  4  5  (array contents without shift)
 3  4  5  1 | 2  3  4  5  1  (shifted 1 time)
 4  5  1  2 | 3  4  5  1  2  (shifted 2 times)
 5  1  2  3 | 4  5  1  2  3  (shifted 3 times)
 1  2  3  4 | 5  1  2  3  4  (shifted 4 times)

formula: i - k + n
results:
i=0: 0 - 4 + 5 = 1
i=1: 1 - 4 + 5 = 2
i=2: 2 - 4 + 5 = 3
i=3: 3 - 4 + 5 = 4
i=4: 4 - 4 + 5 = 5
i=5: 5 - 4 + 5 = 6 => 0
```

*EDIT*: I skipped the parts to check the boundaries for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution 
{

    static void Main(String[] args) 

    {
        int i, j, z;
        string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
        string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp,Int32.Parse);

        int[] temparray = new int[2*n];

        //constraints
        if(n >= 100000 || n < 1 )
            {
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }

        if(k > n || n < 1 )
            {
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }  

        for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
        {
               if(a[i] > 1000000 || a[i] < 1 )
               {
               System.Environment.Exit(1);
               }     
         } 


        for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
            {
            z = (j-k) %n;

            if(z != 0)
                {
                z= (n+ z) %n;
                }

            temparray[z] = a[j];
            }

        //view array
        for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
            {
        Console.Write(temparray[i] + " " );      
            }


    }
}
```